# css grid overflowing parent circle. How to force css grid to comply?

Tags: css, css-grid

so we have a div block and we applied some border-radius to make it a circle.

Next we defined a css grid inside this div block. But this css grid is not containing itself inside circle.

Problem is this grid still sees the div block as a rectangle box-model.
Div block only rendering as circle but its still a box-model deep inside.

any idea how to contain css grid inside the circle only?

I dont want to hide the overflow. I want the grid to respect border and stay inside.

HTML Code :

```
<div> </div>
```

CSS Code :

```
div{
  height: 25vh;
  width: 25vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr:
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: This is not possible without hiding the overflow. Regardless of the visual, **all** HTML elements are *rectangular*. The border-radius does not change this. Hiding the overflow is the only method of removing the interactivity from the overflowing parts.

Answer (score 6):

Without seeing your code it is hard to diagnose the problem, but it sounds like adding overflow: hidden to your circle div might help:

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

See this fiddle for demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sqgkc962/

Comment: amazing thank you!!!!!!! I had a similar issue where the child elements was overflowing off the parent container.